# Git commit message verbs

Tags: git, github

I've created a new Github repo, and I was wondering, is there any convention/standard for the verbs used in commit message subjects ?

I've found [this repo](https://github.com/joelparkerhenderson/git_commit_message) which gives a convention about different verbs to use, but it doesn't seem to be that popular. What are your thoughts on it ? Is there any other convention/standard out there ?

Comment: See https://conventionalcommits.org/ and https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/22b96b9/CONTRIBUTING.md#-commit-message-guidelines

Answer (score 2):

The most important thing is to decide on some standards and use them consistenly accross your team, so that your history does not end up being unreadable.

If however you want to have a starting point you can have a look on several online resources, e.g. https://chris.beams.io/posts/git-commit/

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard but some different conventions.

A good one could be the one used by the angular project used on different other projects :
https://gist.github.com/stephenparish/9941e89d80e2bc58a153#format-of-the-commit-message

Some use emoji instead of the "type" but even if it looks fun, it have some inconvenient... Examples: https://gitmoji.carloscuesta.me/ and https://github.com/dannyfritz/commit-message-emoji

Comment: What conventions do you have in mind ?

Also, I had seen some repos using emojis for commits, but I thought this was more of an aesthetic thing. What are the inconvenients of using these ?

Comment: Each project chooses its convention but some are used by different projects. The 2 I gave for example (angular and emoji). Not all the tools display them correctly like git log in my console and typing them is not as easy as text...